# Is there a site setup control panel for IIS 7.5 and Windows 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, ftp, iis-7.5

In Windows 2003, there was a SharePoint driven control panel that would set up a new IIS web site, FTP, FPSE, and whatnot very easily. Permissions were handled, accounts were added, everything except DNS really.

I work with a smallish ISP, and we would like something like this in Windows 2008. Is there something that we just can't find? Or is it gone and we are back to doing it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is [Plesk](http://www.parallels.com/products/plesk/) already too much for you? Else I would recommend you to search on google for "windows hosting control panel". One of the results is [WebsitePanel](http://websitepanel.codeplex.com/) an open source software. I guess this could be something for you. Else check out the other search results.

Comment: I really wanted something built in; it USED to be built in.  But that open source solution is new to me so I'll give you the bounty. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

<strike>It's still there</strike>, Apparently it's not still there. I'll leave the answer here for informational purposes.

A similar but different tool is in the "Manage Your Server" app, [it's in the IIS Manager](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323972).

> 1. Log on to the Web server computer as an administrator.
> 2. Click Start, point to Settings, and then click Control Panel.
> 3. Double-click Administrative Tools, and then double-click Internet Services Manager.
> 4. Click Action, point to New, and then click Web Site.

As is mentioned by Bill Sempf in the comments below, this does not meet all of the requirements.

Comment: No, that just makes a new site. That's the same as it has been forever. This tool that we have on 2003 adds the FTP for you, add the FTP user, adds FPSE (which is defunct now apparently) etc etc. A more complete solution - saves forever in time.